# Lazy loading img into background not background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lazy-loading

I am wanting to lazyload an image into the css `background` tag, not the `background-image` tag because I also have a semi-transparent overlay which needs to be applied in the following fashion:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60) 75%), url("myimage.jpg") scroll bottom no-repeat;
```

Currently I am using the jquery.lazy library (https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/) but I'm open to using any lazyloading library as long as it supports fade transitions. How could I accomplish this?

Also, I'm not sure how these plugins work but if they simply overwrite anything in the target tag like simply overwriting what is in the `background` tag to add the image - that obviously won't work as that will overwrite my semi-transparent overlay.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here!

Yes, you can use my [jQuery.Lazy plugin](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) for this. But you have to use callbacks to let it work correctly, because this is not a *default* background image. I made you an full example, it should be pretty easy to understand.

And because you are speaking of `fade transitions` I think you mean the `effect` option of this plugin. So I added a `fadeIn` effect. If you don't want that, just remove `effect` and `effectTime` in the options.

```js
$(function() {
    $("div").Lazy({
        effect: 'fadeIn',
        effectTime: 1000,
        beforeLoad: function(e) {
            // before load, store the gradient onto the element data
            e.data("gradient", e.css("background-image"));
        },
        afterLoad: function(e) {
            // afterwards create the wanted background image
            e.css("background-image", e.data("gradient") + "," + e.css("background-image"));
        }
    })
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(255, 255, 255), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60) 75%) scroll bottom no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.lazy/1.7.3/jquery.lazy.min.js"></script>

<div data-src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/ff"></div>
```